# Extending Suffixes in Merge to All Non-by Columns

Tags: r, merge, data.table

`suffixes` in `merge` works only on common column names. Is there anyway to extend this to the rest of the columns as well without manually updating columns before the merge?

That is -

```
df1 <- data.table(
a = c(1,2,3,4,5,6),
b = c('a','b','f','e','r','h'),
d = c('q','l','o','n','q','z')
)

df2 <- data.table(
a = c(1,2,3,4,5,6),
d = c('q','l','o','n','q','z')
)

colnames(merge(df1,df2, by = 'a', suffixes = c("1","2")))
#[1] "a"  "b"  "d1" "d2" what it does
#[1] "a"  "b1" "d1" "d2" what I'd like it to do
```

The current way I'm handling this resembles @mrip's answer.

```
df1 <- data.table(
a = c(1,2,3,4,5,6),
b = c('a','b','f','e','r','h'),
r = c('a','b','f','e','r','h'),
d = c('q','l','o','n','q','z')
)

df2 <- data.table(
a = c(1,2,3,4,5,6),
c = c('a','b','f','e','r','h'),
q = c('a','b','f','e','r','h'),
d = c('q','l','o','n','q','z')
)

dfmerge <- (merge(df1,df2, by = c("a"), suffixes = c("1","2")))

setnames(
dfmerge,
setdiff(names(df1),names(df2)),
paste0(setdiff(names(df1),names(df2)),"1")
)

setnames(
dfmerge,
setdiff(names(df2),names(df1)),
paste0(setdiff(names(df2),names(df1)),"2")
)

colnames(dfmerge)
#[1] "a"  "b1" "r1" "d1" "c2" "q2" "d2"
```

Comment: Presumably you mean `a1` in that last example, not just `a`?

Comment: It's inconvenient, but with the efficiency of `setnames`, I wonder if renaming before you merge will end up being the most straightforward solution.

Comment: @joran, I'm guessing they don't since that is the "by" column.

Comment: @AnandaMahto Gotcha. I agree that there won't be a way to do this (with `merge`) that doesn't involved renaming the columns yourself at some point.

Comment: @MattDowle, I used `data.table` out of habit but I will accept an answer even if it isn't based on data.table. However, data.table compatible answer preferred.

Comment: The point of the `suffixes` argument (in either `data.frame` or `data.table`) is to give the user the ability to distinguish columns that have the same name (which otherwise would be hard after a merge). As such I don't understand why you'd want `merge` to do this. If you don't like the names you have, just change them yourself.

Comment: @eddi, perhaps they want to indicate which `df` the column originally came from

Comment: @RicardoSaporta, you're right.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

A simple solution:

```
mrg<-(merge(df1,df2, by = 'a', suffixes = c("1","2")))
setnames(mrg,paste0(names(mrg),ifelse(names(mrg) %in% setdiff(names(df1),names(df2)),"1","")))
setnames(mrg,paste0(names(mrg),ifelse(names(mrg) %in% setdiff(names(df2),names(df1)),"2","")))

> names(mrg)
[1] "a"  "b1" "d1" "d2"
```

Edit: thanks to comments by Ricardo Saporta for cleaning this up considerably and teaching me a few new tips!

Comment: @RicardoSaporta Yes!  Thanks, I was confused about the.  Cleaned it up.

Comment: @RicardoSaporta Yes again!  Thanks, that will save me a lot of `,sep="")` in the future.  Great tip~

Comment: @eddi, why?   the `by` values are the ones that do NOT require appending a suffix

Comment: @mrip, thanks. You and I are thinking along the same lines. I added the code I'm currently using to the question if you'd like to have a look at it.

Comment: Not that I'm Scrooge but I've given it an upvote for now because I think mrip deserves it as well. I'm waiting for a more deserving answer which involves minimal/no manual extra work as compared to what I was doing, but if none appears then the checkmark is all @mrip's.

Answer (score 6):

Try the following:

```
colnames(
  mergeWithSuffix(df1,df2, by = 'a', suffixes = c("1","2"))
)
[1] "a"   "b.1" "d.1" "d.2"
```

Notice that the original `data.frames` are unharmed.

```
colnames(df1)
[1] "a" "b" "d"

colnames(df2)
[1] "a" "d"
```

The functions are as follows

```
require(data.table)

mergeWithSuffix <- function(x, y, by, suffixes=NULL, ...) {

  # Add Suffixes
  mkSuffix(x, suffixes[[1]], merge.col=by)
  mkSuffix(y, suffixes[[2]], merge.col=by)

  # Merge
  ret <- merge(x, y, by = by, suffixes = NULL, ...)

  # Remove Suffixes
  undoSuffix(x, suffixes[[1]], merge.col=by)
  undoSuffix(y, suffixes[[2]], merge.col=by)
  return(ret)
}

mkSuffix <- function(x, sfx, sep=".", merge.col=NULL)  {
  nms <- setdiff(names(x), merge.col)
  setnames(x, nms, paste(nms, sfx, sep=".") ) 
}

undoSuffix <- function(x, sfx, sep=".", merge.col=NULL) {
  nms <- setdiff(names(x), merge.col)
  setnames(x, nms, sub(paste0(get("sep"), sfx, "$"), "", nms))
}
```

---

Notice that `setnames` works by reference, so the overhead is almost negligible.  Also, as discussed elsewhere, this works equally well on data.frames and data.table

Comment: This answer can be generalized to merge multiple data frames: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8091303/simultaneously-merge-multiple-data-frames-in-a-list

Answer (score 1):

This is an interesting question, and I doubt that extending `merge` would be a straightforward solution unless Matt Dowle and Co. think it's something worth implementing in `merge.data.table`.

Here's one approach that came to mind:

```
DTs <- c("df1", "df2")
suffixes <- seq_along(DTs)

for (i in seq_along(DTs)) {
  Name <- setdiff(colnames(get(DTs[i])), "a")
  setnames(get(DTs[i]), Name, paste(Name, suffixes[i], sep = "."))
}

merge(df1, df2, by = "a") # Will obviously work as you expect now
```

Comment: (I'm too tired to think about whether there are any performance impacts of using `get` the way it was done here....)